# How to get Qustion from answer object in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have two class Question and Answer in models. Both are connected to user by ForeignKey. In a template I want to print all answer of the looged in user. Which is happening easily.  But my problem is **I want to get question corresponding to the answer**.  What will be the query to get the question? models, template and views given below--

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Answer(models.Model):
    answer_text = models.TextField()
    questions = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer_text
```

views:

```
def answered_by_me(request, user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    answers = user.answer_set.all()
    questions = user.question_set.all()
    context = {'answers': answers, 'questions': questions, 'user_id': user_id}
    return render(request, template_name='ans/answered_by_me.html', context=context)
```

template:

```
{% block body %}
    {{ answers }}
    {% if answers %}
        <ul>
            {% for answer in answers %}

                <li> {{ answer }}</li>

            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a new query, unless you want to pass a question id to your view.

Instead of looping the answers, you should loop the questions:

```
{% for question in questions %}
    <li>{{ question }}</li>
    {% for answer in question.answer_set.all %}
    <li> {{ answer }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I think this may work.